# Difference between List<? extends MyClass> and List<MyClass>

Tags: java, generics

What's the difference between `List<? extends MyClass>` and `List<MyClass>`. Don't both mean that I have a list with objects of `MyClass`?

Comment: You will see one difference if you will try to add `MyClass` object to `List<? extends MyClass>` and to `List<MyClass>` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference.  A `List<? extends MyClass>` could refer to a `List<MySubClass>`, which is different than a `List<MyClass>`.  Also, a `List<MySubClass>` is not a `List<MyClass>`, because Java generics are not covariant.

Because the compiler doesn't know *which* subclass the wildcard actually is, it prevents you from calling `add`, to preserve type safety.

Answer (score 1):

`List<? extends MyClass>`, when accepted in a method, gives you a list that cannot have things added for type safety, but can actually be read quite nicely. Since we don't know which subclass of `MyClass` the list is actually, we cam't add `MyClass`. Note that `X extends Y` does not imply `Foo<X> extends Foo<Y>`, due to lack of covariance.

For `List<MyClass>` you can read and write nicely to it.

Comment: @Thilo I'd have to do experimentation for the null case when I have time.

Comment: "Oh, this one again?" Maybe you could help look for/vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`GenericClass<? extends T> g` allows you to use a generic *return* type for a method in `GenericClass`:

```
 T item = g.get(0)
```

`GenericClass<? super T> g` allows you to use a generic *argument* type for a method in `GenericClass`:

```
 T item;
 g.set(0, item)
```

Comment: GenericClass? `get` and `set` are defined in `List`. How they would work for "GenericClass" is completely up for grabs.